# Minimum sample size at the last stage of multistage sampling

Tags: sampling, small-sample

We're conducting a two-stage survey. First stage is schools, second stage is students. What is the minimum number of students per school that we need to sample?

I remember reading that the minimum sample size at the second stage is 2, because otherwise you won't be able to estimate the second stage variance. Is it possible to just sample 1? Can we sample a lot of students in some schools, and just 1 student in other schools? I don't understand why it has to be at least 2 students in each and every school -- can't we get the variance estimate from the schools in which we sample a lot of students?

I'd like to be able to sample just 1 student in some schools. Is there a legitimate way to do that?

Comment: What's goal of the survey analysis (what parameters, associations, do you hope to estimate or test?)  What's the number schools you intend to sample, and how did you choose it?  What is the process for sampling schools?  What differentiates the schools where you want to take a lot of students and the schools where you want to take only 1.

Comment: We are collecting information about students. Demographics, what kinds of school work they do, how they perform on standardized tests, and so on. 

Over a thousand schools, chosen randomly, stratified by school size. 

We have a limited time to ask questions. If we take too long, school administrators will likely just hang up on us. One idea is that, in some schools, we will ask only core questions about a bunch of students. In other schools, we will ask a lot of different questions (including the core questions) about 1 or 2 students.

Comment: I know we can do 2 students -- I am wondering if we can do 1. That way, we can ask even more questions. 

For the questions for which we expect small differences, we need to ask about a lot of students. For the ones where we expect large differences, we are OK asking about fewer students.

Comment: These design decisions appear very questionable to me. Have there been pretests,, feasibility studies,  pilot test,  consideration of multiple, modes of survey,  cognitive question testing? Was there a sample design and sample size calculation that took into account relative costs of recruiting schools vs costs of studying a student in a recruited school, within- and between school variation?  I doubt that an administrator can supply useful information about a "bunch" of students and, I doubt you'll get detailed information about a smaller number without informed consent.

Comment: I can only suggest that you consult a survey professional who can advise you on what is feasible given your resources and experience. I also suggest that you look surveys done by the National Center for Educational Statistics